# Normalize SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, normalization, entity-attribute-value

Can we furthur Normalize this Sql Table
Structue is
Primary key is `ID,Date,NAme,Type`

```
ID  Date          Name            Type           Value 
-----------------------------------------------------


1   08/15/2010    Rating          A+               10       
1   08/15/2010    Rating          A-               10        
1   08/15/2010    Composition     MultipleChoice   33        
1   08/15/2010    Composition     YESNO            33        
1   08/15/2010    Composition     Fillin           33        

1   08/16/2010    Rating          A+               30      
1   08/16/2010    Rating          A-               10        
1   08/16/2010    Composition     MultipleChoice   25       
1   08/16/2010    Composition     YESNO            50        
1   08/16/2010    Composition     Fillin           25
```

and so on

Comment: The data suggests its possible, but you need to supply what the table actually contains before you can expect an answer

Comment: ID,Name,Type are nvarchar
Value is Real

Comment: The data types are not what matters. What matters is what the fields actually *mean*. That's the only way to decide the proper normalizations. For example, is it *ever* the case that two rows with the same value of Name can have different values of Date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks suspiciously like a combination [EAV table](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/avoiding-the-eav-of-destruction/) and history table.  What is its true purpose?  What are the associated tables?

Based on the limited information given, you would normalize it by turning it into a pure history table.  The `Rating` and `Composition` should not be split across rows but should be in decently-named columns. Something like so:

```
ID  Date          Rating_A+     Rating_A-   MultipleChoicePercent  YESNOPercent FillinPercent
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   08/15/2010    10.0          10.0        33.3                    33.3        33.3
1   08/16/2010    30.0          10.0        25.0                    50.0        25.0
```

.
This will allow for simpler and faster: Check constraints, indexes, and queries.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this

[image]

Comment: How do I create foreignKeys in degin Mode using SQL SERVER 2005 Exp

Answer (score 1):

Are types and names going to be out of a specific set? You could break them out into lib tables and reference them. That's the only thing I can think of though.

For example, if your types are always going to just be A1, A2, B1, B2, and C1, you can go make those into a separate table, and then instead of constantly entering A1 into the database, you can have a foreign key off to the table of types that references A1's row.

Comment: Yes it looks like name is functionally dependant on type in which case this would violate 2NF.

Comment: -1 Your suggestion of isolating the natural values into a lookup table has nothing to do with normalization.

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious thing that I can see is breaking out Name and Type to separate tables, but I can't say definitely since I'm not quite sure what they actually represent.